# Android: Como criar um banco de dados Sqlite externo dinamicamente?

Tags: android, sqlite, persistência, portabilidade

Eu tenho pesquisado exaustivamente sobre isto e todos os exemplos que encontrei e testei não funcionaram. Para deixar o código mais organizado eu gostaria de fazer isso usando a classe OpenHelper mas já testei o método openOrCreate () tanto na OpenHelper quanto na própria Activity. Abaixo segue meu código:

```
public class CriaBancoApp extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String NOME_BANCO = "BD_AppNome.db";
    private static final String CAMINHO_BANCO = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/AppNome/Databases/";
    private static final int VERSAO = 1;


    public CriaBancoApp(Context contexto) {
        super(contexto, CAMINHO_BANCO, null, VERSAO); 
       //SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(CAMINHO_BANCO, null); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE NomeTabela (" 
                + "Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + "AutorTraducao TEXT)";
                db.execSQL(sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS NomeTabela");
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

Então eu crio a instância na MainActivity:

```
CriaBancoApp banco = new CriaBancoApp(this);
```

E ao iniciar o app fecha. Em relação ao caminho as pastas do app são criadas antes de criar o banco de dados eu até comentei esta linha para verificar se as pastas são criadas e são. O Manifesto do xml já tem a permissão de escrita que automaticamente inclui a permissão de leitura.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, após pesquisar muito decidi estudar a classe pai SQLiteOpenHelper e descobri que ela usa o contexto para definir o caminho onde será criado o banco de dados. Com base nisso mudei o foco da pesquisa para como personalizar um contexto com o caminho que eu quero. Nesta pesquisa cheguei a esta resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9168969/2272934 que resolveu o problema. Como estava toda em inglês, fiz minha adaptação dessa resposta para o português ficou assim:

Na classe CriaBancoApp modifiquei o construtor:

```
    public CriaBancoApp(Context contexto) {
        super(new ContextoBanco(contexto, CAMINHO_BANCO), NOME_BANCO, null, VERSAO);
    }
```

Então criei uma classe responsável por personalizar o contexto:

```
public class ContextoBanco extends ContextWrapper {
    private static final String DEPURAR_CONTEXTO = "ContextoBanco";
    private String caminho;

    public ContextoBanco(Context base, String caminho) {
        super(base);
        this.caminho = caminho;
    }

    @Override
    public File getDatabasePath(String name)  {
        String caminho_banco = caminho + name;
        if (!caminho_banco.endsWith(".db")) {
            caminho_banco += ".db" ;
        }

        File result = new File(caminho_banco);

        if (!result.getParentFile().exists()) {

            result.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        }

        if (Log.isLoggable(DEPURAR_CONTEXTO, Log.WARN)) {
         Log.w(DEPURAR_CONTEXTO, "getDatabasePath(" + name + ") = " + result.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        return result;
    }

    /* Esta versão é chamada para dispositivos Android >= api-11. */
    @Override
    public SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase(String name, int mode, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {
        return openOrCreateDatabase(name,mode, factory);
    }

    /* Esta versão é chamada para dispositivos Android < api-11 */
    @Override
    public SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase(String name, int mode, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory) {
        SQLiteDatabase result = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(getDatabasePath(name), null);
        if (Log.isLoggable(DEPURAR_CONTEXTO, Log.WARN)) {
         Log.w(DEPURAR_CONTEXTO, "openOrCreateDatabase(" + name + ",,) = " + result.getPath());
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

E na MainActivity além de criar uma instância da classe CriaBancoApp é necessário fazer uma consulta para que o banco de dados seja criado:

```
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        CriaBancoApp banco = new CriaBancoApp(this);
        String[] campos = {"Id","Nome","Idade","Etc"};
        String condicao = " Id > 0 ";
        Cursor dados = null;

        db = banco.getReadableDatabase();

        dados = db.query("Nome_da_Tabela", campos, condicao, null, null, null, null);

        if(dados != null) {

            if(dados.moveToNext()) {
                // Registro encontrado
            } else {
                // Não há registros na tabela
            }
        }
```

Mesmo eu mesmo tendo achado minha resposta me senti no dever de publicar para ajudar outros que podem precisar, afinal foi bem demorado pra mim achar.